# DockPanelSuite .Can I hide/Disable x and down arrow + tab header

Tags: c#, dockpanel-suite

Really like the free Dockpanelsuite.New to it and was wondering if possible.

I would like to hide the x and down arrow + tabheader

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Is this some library or just Tab of framework?

Answer (score 3):

The close button can be hidden on a per-DockContent basis via the CloseButtonVisible property of the DockContent.

Currently the window list button cannot be hidden as easily.  I have logged a new feature request for this option:  https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite/issues/29

Answer (score 0):

Hide the close button using `CloseButtonVisible` property for the DockContent.

```
content.CloseButtonVisible = false;
```